# How to find the container image path based on pod name or container ID

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift

Let's say I have a 3 node cluster (master01, node01, node02)

How can I find the running container path on node?
I can see container ID by "oc describe pod"

```
Container ID:   docker://9982c309a3fd8c336c98201eff53a830a1c56a4cf94c2861c52656855cba3558
```

eg: on node 01, I can see a lot of directories under "/var/lib/openshift/openshift.local.volumes/pods/"; but not sure how this map to pod names or container names.
Seems inactive container maps/mounts but how to do a sage clean up ?

Any help really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to list the container image by pod name:

`kubectl get pods POD_NAME -o=jsonpath='{..image}'`

Source: [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/)

Comment: Thanks for this tip. 
But I was looking for the path which got it from almost same method as below.

`kubectl get pods <pod name> -o jsonpath={.metadata.uid}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers.

I have found it from another group and given below.

**Method 1:**

`kubectl get pods <pod name> -o jsonpath={.metadata.uid}`

Then look up the uid returned in `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/<uid>` (or `/var/lib/openshift/pods/<uid>`) on the node where the pod is located.

**Methods 2:**

`kubectl describe pod <podname>`

Get the **container id** from there.

Then run a `docker inspect <containerid>` on the node

Then look up the uid returned in `/var/lib/kubelet/pods/<uid>` (or `/var/lib/openshift/pods/<uid>`) on the node where the pod is located.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, all the container filesystems + images live under your docker home directory which defaults to /var/lib/docker. You can also see if it has been custom configured by looking at the current dockerd process:

```
ps -Af | grep dockerd
```

Since you are running docker as your runtime. You can use to clean up all the garbage:

```
docker system prune -a --force
```

Basically, it prunes all the exited containers and the images that are not being used by any container.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this tip. But I was looking for the path which got it from almost same method as below. 'kubectl get pods <pod name> -o jsonpath={.metadata.uid}'